# Java get parameter values through reflection

Tags: java, reflection, parameters

I have a set of classes that are all very similar. Currently I'm using reflection to access and invoke the choose method below. What I need to be able to get is the `myList` parameter. I've tried using proxies but, I'm a beginner with Java and don't understand how to implement and use them.

```
public int choose(List<Object> myList, Object card, Object color, State state)
{
      int answer = -1;
      // sort through myList and set answer to index of desired object
      return answer;
}
```

Is there some better way to get this parameter in Java without using AspectJ? And if so, could you provide an example?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you're using reflection to invoke the method, the handling of parameters inside the method is the same as if you would invoke the method regulary.

Comment: An example of what? It's unclear what you want and when you want it

Comment: At runtime I want to be able to invoke the choose method and get the passed value of the `myList` parameter. I have 100's of classes with a similar choose method and I need to analyze the passed list of objects during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
class State
{
}

class MyClass
{
    public int choose(List<Object> myList, Object card, Object color, State state)
    {
        int answer = -1;
        System.out.println("myList has " + myList.size() + " elements");
        for (Object o : myList)
        {
            System.out.println("element -> " + o);
        }
        // sort through myList and set answer to index of desired object
        return answer;
    }
}

public static int InvokeChoose(Object obj) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException
{
    Method m = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("choose", List.class, Object.class, Object.class, State.class);
    List<Object> someList = new ArrayList<>();
    someList.add(Integer.valueOf(0));
    someList.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
    someList.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
    Object result = m.invoke(obj, someList, new Object(), new Object(), new State());
    return ((Number)result).intValue();
}

public static void TryIt()
{
    MyClass c = new MyClass();
    try
    {
        int result = InvokeChoose(c);
        System.out.println("the result is: " + result);
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
myList has 3 elements
element -> 0
element -> 1
element -> 2
the result is: -1
```